# Left outer join of datatable with linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have two `DataTable`s:

```
DataTable dtFields = new DataTable("tmpFieldTable");                
dtFields.Columns.Add("FieldID");
dtFields.Columns.Add("CDGroupID");
dtFields.Columns.Add("CDCaption");
dtFields.Columns.Add("fldIndex");
```

and

```
DataTable dtCDGroup = new DataTable("tmpCDGroup");               
dtCDGroup.Columns.Add("CDGroupID");
dtCDGroup.Columns.Add("Name");
dtCDGroup.Columns.Add("Priority");
```

I am using following LINQ expression to join these tables:

```
var resultList = dtFields.AsEnumerable()
                         .Join(dtCDGroup.AsEnumerable(),
                               fieldList => fieldList.Field<string>("CDGroupID"),
                               cd => cd.Field<string>("CDGroupID"),
                               (fieldList, cd) => new
                               {
                                   FieldID = fieldList.Field<string>("FieldID"),
                                   CdGroup = cd.Field<string>("Name"),
                                   CDCaption = fieldList.Field<string>("CDCaption"),
                                   Priority = (cd.Field<string>("Priority") ?? "99"),
                                   fldIndex = fieldList.Field<string>("fldIndex").ToString()
                               })
                         .OrderBy(result => result.Priority)
                         .ThenBy(result => result.fldIndex);
```

How can I perform left outer join with these `DataTable`s?

Comment: Im assuming you mean left **outer** join

Answer (score 0):

Left join are not natively offered using lambda expression. but you can achieve this using GroupJoin and SelectMany method.

```
var result = new string[] { "A", "B" }.GroupJoin(new string[] { "B" }, l => l, r => r, (l, r) => new { l, r }).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(result.Count());
```

this will result result[0].r.Count() = 0 and result[1].r.Count() = 1.

Hope this will help.

Regards.

Comment: for more information have a look at http://jcmartialarts.co.uk/CSharp/Using-Lambda-Expressions-To-LEFT-JOIN-Tables/43

Answer (score 0):

Just add [`DefaultIfEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to your table:

```
resultList = dtFields.AsEnumerable() 
                     .Join(dtCDGroup.AsEnumerable().DefaultIfEmpty(), 
                           fieldList => fieldList.Field<string>("CDGroupID"), 
                           cd => cd.Field<string>("CDGroupID"), 
                           (fieldList, cd) => new 
                           { 
                               FieldID = fieldList.Field<string>("FieldID"), 
                               CdGroup = cd.Field<string>("Name"), 
                               CDCaption = fieldList.Field<string>("CDCaption"), 
                               Priority = (cd.Field<string>("Priority") ?? "99"), 
                               fldIndex = fieldList.Field<string>("fldIndex").ToString() 
                           }) 
                     .OrderBy(result => result.Priority) 
                     .ThenBy(result => result.fldIndex);
```